# Trying to get tie results on column not included in order by

Tags: sql-server

Given the following result sets, sorted in descending order on column **Date**.

[image]

I want to use `Top` clause like:

```
select top 4 *
from donation d
order by d.Date desc;
```

Which give me the following result:

[image]

Even though I limit my result with top 4, I want to be able to include the last row, because it is tie with the last record (id : 5) based on the Name.

Comment: Show us your query!

Comment: `order by d.Date desc` will return the row with id = 3 as last.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query first selects the names of the people in the top 4 dates (in a Common Table Expression), then uses these names to shown all their data. I guess that is what you want.

```
;WITH Top4Names AS
(
    SELECT TOP 4 [Name]
    FROM donation
    ORDER BY [Date] DESC
)
SELECT d.id, d.[Name], d.Amount, d.[Date]
FROM donation d
INNER JOIN Top4Names t
ON t.[Name] = d.[Name]
ORDER BY d.[Date] DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks, That's what I wanted